# Error running CONNECT validation suite

Tags: maven, glassfish

Not too sure if this is the right place to ask this question.

I downloaded CONNECT code from github and tried to build it.

I have successfully completed the pre-requisites given in this link - https://connectopensource.atlassian.net/wiki/display/CONNECT4/Building+CONNECT+4.4+from+Source

Then I tried mvn clean install or mvn clean install -Dmaven.test.skip=true and got the error

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-antrun-plugin:1.7:run (setup-selfsigned-certs) on project ValidationSuite: 
An Ant BuildException has occured: Warning: Could not find file /Users/XXX/projects/originalConnect/CONNECT/Product/SoapUI_Test/ValidationSuite/target/test-classes/chaincerts/gateway.jks to copy.
```

Then I ran this command (got it from readme file on github)

mvn -e verify -Dstandalone -Dproperties.dir=/Users/XXX/Downloads/glassfish4/glassfish/domains/domain1/config

And got this error

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal com.github.redfish4ktc.soapui:maven-soapui-extension-plugin:4.5.1.2:test-verify (test-verify) on project ValidationSuite: SoapUI Test(s) failed: see logs and/or check the printReport (if necessary, set the option to true) -> [Help 1] 
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal com.github.redfish4ktc.soapui:maven-soapui-extension-plugin:4.5.1.2:test-verify (test-verify) on project ValidationSuite: SoapUI Test(s) failed: see logs and/or check the printReport
```

I am building CONNECT 4.4.1 and my operating system is Mac OS X 10.10.2

I will be thankful if anyone please point me in the right direction. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This has been resolved now.

Issue was that I had been using glassfish4. It turns out that Connect 4.4.1 is not compatible with glassfish4. Switching it to glassfish 3 solved the issue.